# Change view responsively on Kendo UI Scheduler

Tags: kendo-ui, responsive-design, scheduler

I have this app that uses Kendo UI scheduler, and I now have two views:

```
views: [
            { type: "day", selected: false, majorTick: majorTick },
            { type: "week", selected: true, majorTick: majorTick },
        ]
```

The problem is I need to change the view to `day` if the user is in mobile, and leave it on `week` otherwise.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found this solution, first I check whether the app is in mobile like this:

```
detectmobile(): boolean {
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
        || (window.innerWidth <= 800 && window.innerHeight <= 600)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then I simply workout my booleans:

```
 let detectMobile = this.detectmobile();
 let isDay = detectMobile;
 let isWeek = !detectMobile;
```

Finally I feed them to `jQuery("#scheduler").kendoScheduler`:

```
views: [
            { type: "day", selected: isDay, majorTick: majorTick },
            { type: "week", selected: isWeek, majorTick: majorTick },
        ],
```